# Shopify Orders API response: Discount missing with orders line item

Tags: shopify

We are having an issue with Shopify order API, while downloading orders with their items, we are not getting discounted line item amount.

An orders is having discounted item "Discount (shoe sale)" with amount -67.50. This amount is not getting with orders from Shopify. There is no node available in orders (also in product) response that returns orders line item discount.

PFA,[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a known and very frustrating problem. I have asked Shopify to fix this oversight for 2 years now, about 30 times, to no avail. You are SOL.

You cannot do proper accounting with the Shopify Order API at this time. Perhaps in the future they will fix it. For now, you have to work without knowing the discounts applied per line item. If there is only one line item, of course you can work it backwards... but if there is more than one, you're screwed.